# Installing Tailwind CSS v2.0+ into Laravel 8 works but does nothing when run

Tags: laravel, webpack, tailwind-css, postcss

I'm trying to install Tailwind CSS v2.0 into a clean Laravel install, but when I run `npm run prod` (or `dev`), the compiled CSS file is just a copy of the source.

The steps I'm taking:

```
> laravel new twtest
> cd twtest
> php artisan -V
# Laravel Framework 8.16.1
> npm install
> npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
> touch postcss.config.js
# Add the postCss default from https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation
# Add the three @tailwind commands into /resources/css/app.css
> npm run dev
```

This compiles successfully, but the output CSS (in `public/css/app.css`) lists the same three tailwind commands where it should have all the compiled Tailwind CSS:

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the latest versions using:

```
npm install -D laravel-mix@latest tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest --save-dev
```

Double-check that your package.json contains the latest script entries to support the latest version of Laravel Mix.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
```

And also, remove the postcss.config.js and generate the tailwind.config.js at the same time as postcss.config.js.

```
npx tailwindcss init -p
```

Add the following into you /resources/css/app.css.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

The complete steps would be:

```
laravel new twtest
cd twtest
npm install -D laravel-mix@latest tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest --save-dev
npx tailwindcss init
# Add the three @tailwind entries into /resources/css/app.css
npm run prod
```